# API rate limiting for authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

I was considering AWS API gateway for authentication. I would need to implement some sort of rate limiting to prevent abuse. AWS offers rate limiting by IP address. However, the lowest frequency allowed is 100 requests/ 5 minutes / IP Address. I feel this approach does not secure against brute force attacks since there can be 28,800 requests / day / IP. I would ideally like to go through a programmatic API based authentication. Are there any solutions for this.

I feel very comfortable with this approach if I can have a rate limiting by IP rate of 3 - 6 requests / 15 minutes (100x decrease). However, I don't think AWS offers this solution. Are there other providers which can provide a REST API POST method over HTTPS with rate limiting by IP of 3 - 6 requests / IP address?

I have email verification for registration and password reset. Should I add email verification to login (I don't think it is necessary)? All of these authentication components are API based.

Should I be comfortable with the limitation of API AWS rate limiting by IP or should I consider a new approach to authentication?

Comment: the AWS limits are perfect - forget about it and move on !  enjoy

Comment: I am not understanding your comment. Are you saying that I should use the AWS API based approach?

Comment: "Should I be comfortable with the limitation of API AWS rate limiting" ... yes, their values (28,000 a day) are fine.  just one opinion!